# RadSpell display redlines

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a `multiline checkbox`. I want to use `RadSpell`. 
But everytime I insert text on the `textbox` it doesn't display `red lines`.

How can i do this?

here is my code.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" 
              Columns="51" Width="401px" Font-Size="10" Font-Names="Calibri" />
<telerik:radspell id="RadSpell1" runat="server" DictionaryLanguage="English"
     controltocheck="textbox1" spellcheckprovider="PhoneticProvider" 
     supportedlanguages="en-US,English" ButtonType="None"/>
```

**NOTE**: No buttons needed. 

I just want to show all the words that are misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

That's a browser feature - inline spellchecking. All modern browsers have it. Well, IE doesn't, but why should we call it modern? ;-)
What RadSpell can do for you is a popup with suggestions and information.

EDIT: Forgot to mention you can trigger RadSpell's check programmatically: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/spell-client-side-api.html. Look for the startSpellCheck() method. For example in the onblur event.